# Strange behavior of canvas javascript

Tags: html, canvas

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var bee = new Image();

var height = 0, width = 0;



bee.onload = function () {
init();
}


init();

function init()
{



 console.log(ctx);
bee.src = '\\assets\\images\\ant_256.png';
width = canvas.width;
height = canvas.height;
console.log(height + '-' + width);
console.log(bee);
ctx.drawImage(bee, 10, 10, 10, 10);

}
```

You see I have called the Init(); function two times, if i comment any of the functions the picture does not display on my canvas, how ever it is displaying now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this code ... Ive added jquery and on its onload fixed some DOM elements binding sequence

```
$(function () {
myCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas = document.querySelector('body').appendChild(myCanvas);
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.id = 'shipcanvas';
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); 

    bee.onload = function () { 
}

bee.src = '\\assets\\images\\ant_256.png';
    ctx.drawImage(name, x, y);



});
```

Comment: working like a charm :) what if i remove the bee.onload = function ()? Its kind useless for me

Comment: Its just for the any action you want to perform when the image is being loaded like showing a spinner or loading gif. or something. It wont effect your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
ctx.drawImage(bee, 10, 10, 10, 10);
```

needs to happen after the image has been downloaded, downloading starts on

bee.src = '\assets\images\ant_256.png';

which is part of init function.

The first call to init begins the download and without the image ...

```
ctx.drawImage(bee, 10, 10, 10, 10);
```

... it can not draw until the image has been downloaded, currently not the first call.

The second call to init after onload event draws the image.

**Solution**

Move

```
 bee.src = '\\assets\\images\\ant_256.png';
```

to the location of the first call to init(); which is the one in the middle of the page.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    bee = new Image(),
    height = 0,
    width = 0;

bee.onload = function () {
   init();
}

bee.src = '\\assets\\images\\ant_256.png';

function init() {
   console.log(ctx);
   width = canvas.width;
   height = canvas.height;
   console.log(height + '-' + width);
   console.log(bee);
   ctx.drawImage(bee, 10, 10, 10, 10);
}
```